# Is there any way to add perturbation to a variable in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, minimize

I have a `101x82` size matrix called `A`. I am trying to minimize an objective function `obj_fun`, whose value is computed indirectly using `A`.

Now in order to minimize this objective function `obj_fun`, I need to perturb the values of `A`. I want to check if `obj_fun` is going down in values or not. If not, then I need to do perturb/change values of `A` to a certain percentage such that it minimizes `obj_fun`. Keep on perturbing/changing values of `A` until we get minimum `obj_fun`. My average value of `A` before any perturbation is ~ 1.1529e+003.

Does any one have suggestion how can I do this? Also, I care a bit about speed i.e. the method/algorithm should not be too slow. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add random Gaussian noise to `A`:

```
A = 0; % seed value for A with something more interesting than 0
best = obj_fun(A);

for iter = 1:max_iter % max_iter should be the maximum number of iterations
  newA = A + normrnd(0, 1, size(A));
  newObj = obj_fun(A);
  if( newObj < best )
    best = newObj;
    A = newA;
  end
end
```

Comment: `normrand` is not showing to be a correct function - `normrand not found`. Also, I would like to perturb values of `A` such that the resultant values are also of magnitude close to `A`. My average value of `A` is ~ `1.1529e+003`

Comment: My bad, it should be `normrnd`. The first two arguments to `normrnd` are the mean and standard deviation, respectively, of the perturbations you want generated. You can change the `0` in the sample for `1.1529+003` if you need the perturbations to have that value on average.

Comment: By the way, you need the statistics toolbox: http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/normrnd.html